# how to type property as key on forEach in typescript?

Tags: typescript

this is my code:

```
type BoadsSagasKeys = 'createBoard' | 'getBoards' | 'fetchBoard';

beforeEach(() => {
 jest.resetAllMocks();
});

Object.keys(Api.boards).forEach((k: string) => {
Api.boards[k as BoadsSagasKeys] = jest.fn() as
 jest.Mocked<typeof Api['boards'][keyof BoadsSagasKeys]>; // ERROR on keyof
});
```

i want jest.Mocked to match the current key, but this don't work, how do i type for the key in this case?

ATM, I am settling by doing nothing assigning on jest.fn() and doing this:

```
(Api.boards.fetchBoard as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(
      () =>
        Promise.resolve({
          data: { board: getFetchedMockBoard(mockBoardData._id) }
        }) as Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>
    );
```

as jest.Mock works

Answer (score 2):

`BoadsSagasKeys` <strike>is not a type that has keys, rather</strike> is a type alias of a union of string constants, therefore <strike>the `keyof` statement before `BoadsSagasKeys` is invalid</strike> `keyof BoadsSagasKeys` will return a union of the keys of `string`. Simply: `keyof BoadsSagasKeys === keyof string`. (thanks to Mike for correcting!)
That means that what you did was trying to index `typeof Api['boards']` with `keyof string`, which is probably an error since `Api['boards']` doesn't extend `string`.

What I believe you meant to do was this:

```
type BoadsSagasKeys = 'createBoard' | 'getBoards' | 'fetchBoard';

beforeEach(() => {
 jest.resetAllMocks();
});

Object.keys(Api.boards).forEach((k: string) => {
Api.boards[k as BoadsSagasKeys] = jest.fn() as
 jest.Mocked<typeof Api['boards'][BoadsSagasKeys]>; // no `keyof` before `BoadsSagasKeys`
});
```

Comment: Small note to supplement, `BoadsSagasKeys` *does* have keys, and `keyof BoadsSagasKeys` is a valid statement, but actually matches the keys within the string prototype. So `keyof BoadsSagasKeys` really matches `'anchor' | 'big' | 'blink' | 'bold' | 'charAt' | 'charCodeAt' | ...`.

Comment: @MikeHill good point, my bad. I'll edit my answer accordingly.